# How to set C version to C11?

Tags: c, ubuntu, clang

When I run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >=  201710L
  printf("We are using C18!\n");
#elif __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
  printf("We are using C11!\n");
#elif __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
  printf("We are using C99!\n");
#else
  printf("We are using C89/C90!\n");
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

It tolds me that I'm using **C18** version. How to change it to **C11** or **C99** as **default**?

I'm using UBUNTU **20.04** and gcc version: **9.3.0**.

I've also already install clang-11 with this command: `apt-get install clang-11 lldb-11 lld-11`.

What's next?

Comment: Use flag `-std=c11` when you compile.

Comment: `clang -std=c11 file.c -o file`

Comment: @AmmarFaizi how to make it as default?

Comment: @KevinkunOfficial Use a makefile with all the required options provided.

Comment: I don't think there is an option to make it default. Just explicitly provide this flag is very trivial in any case. If you use Makefile, then edit your Makefile to provide this flag on compilation.

Comment: Some build system usually provides a way to override compiler flags through command line argument. Something like `make CFLAGS="-std=c11"`.

Comment: @AmmarFaizi  i'm sorry, i don't quite understand. But how to edit Makefile for C? This is my first time learning programming.

Comment: If you're learning then just learn the latest version. It won't be much different from C11

Comment: How do you compile and link? If you don't use "make", simply add it to your command line.

Comment: @phuclv I thought C11 is the latest version. The program says i'm using C18.

Comment: @thebusybee yes, i'm using **make**. And i want to change it to C11 as default. Is there a way? I try this `make CFLAGS="-std=c11"` but it says **No target specified and no makefile found**.

Comment: no, how is 2011 newer than 2018? Although it's a little bit weird since [C18 is the same as C17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C18_(C_standard_revision)). *C17 addressed defects in C11 without introducing new language features* so they're essentially the same. The next version is C2x

Comment: in gcc (which has mostly the same command line options as Clang) C17 is exactly the same as C11 except for the larger version sring, because [in C11 mode it also applies all the C17 defect fixes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html)

Comment: Hm, I strongly suggest to show us how you 1) compiled the source you show us, and 2) read the manual page of `make`. You need to provide a Makefile or a target, if you want to apply `make`'s built-in rules, on the command line. `make`'s error message is clear and to the point.